# How to execute a shell script in Crystal while capturing output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, crystal-lang

I want to execute a shell script while handling stdout and stderr output. Currently I execute commands using `Process.run`, with `shell=false` and three pipes for stdin, stdout and stderr. I spawn fibers to read from stdout and stderr and log (or otherwise process) the output. This works pretty well for individual commands, but fails horribly for scripts.

I could simply set `shell=true` when calling `Process.run`, but looking at the Crystal source it seems that merely prepends "sh" to the commandline. I've tried prepending "bash" and it didn't help.

Things like redirection (`>file`) and pipes (e.g. `curl something | bash`) don't seem to work with `Process.run`

For example, to download a shell script and execute it, I tried:

> cmd = %{bash -c "curl http://dist.crystal-lang.org/apt/setup.sh" | bash}
>
> Process.run(cmd, ...)

The initial `bash` was added in the hope that it would enable the pipe operator. It doesn't seem to help. I also tried executing each command separately:

> script.split("\n").reject(/^#/, "").each { Process.run(...) }

But of course, that still fails when a command uses redirection or pipes. For example, the command `echo "deb http://dist.crystal-lang.org/apt crystal main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/crystal.list` simply outputs:

> "deb http://dist.crystal-lang.org/apt crystal main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/crystal.list`

It might work if I used the ``` `` ``` backticks method of execution instead; but then I wouldn't be able to capture the output in real time.

Comment: you need to move the pipeline into the `bash -c` in the first case to get it to invoke. You're fighting against `shell=false`, though, which is the thing that would allow you to use shell syntax directly.

Comment: @Petesh Sadly, setting `shell=true` doesn't help any.

Comment: @Petesh Moving the pipeline into the `bash -c` call seems to work, however. So...why doesn't `shell=true` work? Surely it's pretty much the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm basing my understanding on reading the source code of the `run.cr` file. The behaviour is very similar to other languages in how it deals with commands and arguments.

Without `shell=true`, the default behaviour of `Process.run` is to use the command as the **executable** to run. This means that the string needs to be a program name, without any arguments, e.g. `uname` would be a valid name as there's a program on my system called `uname` in `/usr/bin`.

If you ever got behaviour of successfully using `%{bash -c "echo hello world"}` with `shell=false`, then something is wrong - the default behaviour should have been to try to run a program called `bash -c "echo hello world"`, which is unlikely to exist on any system.

Once you pass in 'shell=true', then it does `sh -c <command>`, which will allow strings like `echo hello world` as a command to work; this will also allow redirections and pipelines to work.

The `shell=true` behaviour can generally be interpreted as doing the following:

```
cmd = "sh"
args = [] of String
args << "-c" << "curl http://dist.crystal-lang.org/apt/setup.sh | bash"
Process.run(cmd, args, …)
```

Note that I'm using an array of arguments here - without the array of arguments, you don't have any control over how the arguments are passed into the shell.

> The reason why the first version, with or without `shell=true` doesn't work is because the pipeline is **outside** the `-c`, which is the command you're sending to bash.

Comment: I think the problem was due to the fact I was splitting the command string into `cmd` (a string) and `args` (an array) and then calling `Process.new(cmd, args, ...)`. Even with `shell=true`, it didn't work - probably because I had already split the `|` into an argument of its own...

Comment: Basically, I ended up calling `Process.new("curl", ["http://dist.crystal-lang.org/apt/setup.sh", "|", "bash"], shell: true)`. And of course this didn't work. To support `shell=true`, I needed to modify my wrapper function to avoid splitting the command into words if `shell` is true.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is a UNIX problem. The parent process must be capable to access the STDOUT of the child process. Using a pipe you must start a shell process that will run the whole command, including the `| bash` and not just `curl $URL`. In Crystal this is:

```ruby
command = "curl http://dist.crystal-lang.org/apt/setup.sh | bash"
io = MemoryIO.new
Process.run(command, shell: true, output: io)
output = io.to_s
```

Or if you want to duplicate what Crystal does for you:

```ruby
Process.run("sh", {"-c", command}, output: io)
```

Answer (score 2):

or if you want to call a shell script and get the output i just tried with crystal 0.23.1 and it's work !

```
def screen
    output = IO::Memory.new
     Process.run("bash", args: {"lib/bash_scripts/installation.sh"}, output: output)
     output.close
    output.to_s
end
```